# Join two datasets, keep only the row with date immediately prior to date

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset with the date the patient had a procedure

```
data1<-tribble(
  ~MRN, ~date_in_room,
  1, "2015-01-02"
) %>% mutate(date_in_room = as.Date(date_in_room))
```

And a second dataset with a lot of blood pressure measurements taken over the days prior to the procedure.  There are three different blood pressure measurements:  sbp, dbp, mean:

```
library(dplyr)

data2<-tribble(
  ~MRN, ~event, ~date, ~value,
  1, "sbp", "2014-12-31", 120,
  1, "sbp", "2015-01-01", 119,
  1, "sbp", "2015-01-02", 125,
  1, "dbp", "2015-01-01", 80,
  1, "dbp", "2015-01-02", 84,
  1, "mean", "2015-01-01", 100
)%>% mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

I would like to join the two datasets, but only keep the blood pressure measurement of each type from the date closest *prior* to the date of the procedure (usually the day before, could be more).

```
desired<-tribble(
  ~mrn, ~event, ~date, ~value, ~date_in_room,
  1, "sbp", "2015-01-01", 119, "2015-01-02",
  1, "dbp", "2015-01-01", 80, "2015-01-02",
  1, "mean", "2015-01-01", 100, "2015-01-02"
) %>% mutate(date_in_room = as.Date(date_in_room),
date=as.Date(date)
```

I figure it's something like

```
data1 |> 
  group_by(MRN, event) |> 
  left_join(data2, by=MRN) |>
...?
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Apologies - I think I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `closest()` helper function in `join_by()`. For more details, take a look at the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/reference/join_by.html).

```r
library(dplyr)

left_join(data1, data2, join_by(MRN, closest(date_in_room > date)))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
    MRN date_in_room event date       value
  <dbl> <date>       <chr> <date>     <dbl>
1     1 2015-01-02   sbp   2015-01-01   119
2     1 2015-01-02   dbp   2015-01-01    80
3     1 2015-01-02   mean  2015-01-01   100
```

### Data

I've modified your data a bit so that the `date` columns are of class `date`.

```
data1<-tribble(
  ~MRN, ~date_in_room,
  1, "2015-01-02"
) %>% mutate(date_in_room = as.Date(date_in_room))

data2<-tribble(
  ~MRN, ~event, ~date, ~value,
  1, "sbp", "2014-12-31", 120,
  1, "sbp", "2015-01-01", 119,
  1, "sbp", "2015-01-02", 125,
  1, "dbp", "2015-01-01", 80,
  1, "dbp", "2015-01-02", 84,
  1, "mean", "2015-01-01", 100
) %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about that function - there's one more step - I need the closest for each of sbp, dbp, and mean.  (There are more columns in the dataset, so i need to somehow group_by the "event" variable)

Comment: @jpryan28 I would suggest to modify your `data1` to include an `event` column, so that we can `join_by` both `MRN` and `event`.